# Law of Sines in Java

Tags: java

So I am trying to write a program for my AP comp sci class in High School, and we are told to find the angle measures of a triangle with only the side lengths given, I have used the law of cosigns to find the first angle and am trying to use the law of sines to find the second, however it doesn't work. I have read all the other threads over this and have added the `Math.toRadians()` line to help fix it, but it still doesn't work. Here is my code(plz excuse the mess it is still a work in progress):

```
    double s1 = 0;
    double s2 = 0;
    double s3 = 0;
    double angles1 = 0;
    double angles2 = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter side 1 of your triangle");
     s1 = key.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side 2 of your triangle");
     s2 = key.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side 3 of your triangle");
     s3 = key.nextDouble();       

    angles1 = Math.acos((s3*s3-s2*s2-s1*s1)/(2*s1*s2)); // angle from side 3

    angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angles1)) * s2 / s3);


    angles1 = angles1 * 57.3;
    angles1 = Math.round(angles1);


    angles2 = angles2 * 57.3;
    angles2 = Math.round(angles2);





    System.out.println(" Angle 1 " + angles1);
    System.out.println(" Angle 2 " + angles2);
```

Comment: `angles1` is already in radians, you don't want to do `Math.toRadians` again.  You probably do want to do `angles1 = Math.toDegrees(angles1)` instead of the `* 57.3` though.

Comment: First you need to use law of Cosine to find angle C and then use the law of Sines to get the other 2 angles.

Comment: non of these work for some reason

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Specifically: `If your program throws an exception, have you included the exception, with both the message and the stack trace?` and `If your program produces different results to what you expected, have you stated what you expected, why you expected it, and the actual results?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.acos returns a value already in radians, so just remove the Math.toRadians and it will work fine:

```
angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(angles1) * s2 / s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.acos Returns the arc cosine of a value; the returned angle is in the range 0.0 through pi in radians, then replace

```
 angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angles1)) * s2 / s3);
```

by

```
 angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(angles1) * s2 / s3);
```

....

```
angles1 = Math.acos((s3*s3-s2*s2-s1*s1)/(2*s1*s2)); // angle from side 3
```

That's wrong replace by

```
angles1 = Math.acos((s3*s3+s2*s2-s1*s1)/(2*s1*s2)); // angle from side 3
```

and

```
angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angles1)) * s2 / s3);
```

by

```
angles2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angles1)) * s2 / s1);
```